# Changing age and size of rigged character

Tags: mesh, rigging, makehuman

I have some meshes, which have the same topology, but different sizes. In my case my meshes represent the same character with different age.
When rigging such a character, I'd like to be able to change the size of the armature at the same time of the age of the character.
When just mixing both meshes together and having a shape key which represents the characters age, one of the meshes doesn't match the character anymore.
Is there some way to ensure, that both the mesh and the armature change at the same time?

Comment: Hi, a bit complex to understand as it is now, can you share some more mesh and rigging details? If you could share the file (use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post the provided link in question) this could be probably easier to understand, and perhaps solve.